# how add custom fild to all objects of django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i have db where is companies and custom users, i want add custom field for different companies. Example: user have only NAME, if company is "EXAMPLE": user have fields only NAME and AGE, elif "VIN": user have only NAME and SIZE and AGE and WORK, else: only name. How add this custom fields and update it. Thanks, sory for my English))

Company 1:

- name
  "+add field"

company2:
-name
-age
"+add field"

company 3:
-name
-age
-size
"+add field"

I try many to many, many to one, simple fields, dont work how i want. I wand many custom field how i can edit for every user

Answer (score 0):

you must have separated models that refers OneToOne key to user model like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age= models.IntegerField()

class Vin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age= models.IntegerField()
    size= models.IntegerField()
    work= models.CharField(max_length=30)
```